# measuring the time a participant spends on each item

Tags: grammar

I am interested in doing an experiment which requires to measure the time a participant spends on each sentence. Does the psychopy has this feature ? If yes, I would be grateful if you could help me with it.

Also, can anyone provide a private tuition about how to design my experiment?

Best regards,
Sami

Comment: This is quite far off-topic here, this site is about *programming* as in computer programming

Comment: Not about programming at all, but design  of an experiment in linguistics